# Pandas: Merging dataframes on a string column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and I'm currently working on a project where I have to merge two dataframes. One dataframe, which is called cancer_df, is cancer incidencies by county, year, sex, gender, etc. The other dataframe, which is called hspa_df, is a health score by county and year (FYI, it's only counties in California). I would like to combine my two dataframe on county and year. [Here is the cancer dataframe before the merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8IGh.png) and [Here is the hspa dataframe before the merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnIUE.png)

Then I imported my data and tried the following merge:

```
merged_df= pd.merge(cancer_df, hspa_df, on="County" , how="outer")
```

However, this seems to append the data not merge it. It adds my hspa_df at the end and fills the top of the variable they share in common as NaNs. Why is this happening? I have successfully used this merge with other dataframes, but i merged them on numerical columns, not string.
[Here is the merged dataframes head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JRKU.png) and [Here is the merged dataframes tail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfqC1.png)

Comment: You need to change `how` to `inner` to use the intersection of keys from both frames.

Comment: when i do that it only keeps one county. However, they share 46 counties in common (for each year).

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to combine my two dataframe on county and year

```
merged_df = pd.merge(cancer_df, hspa_df, on=['County', 'Year'] )
```

whether you want to do inner, left, right, etc. join, depends on your usecase, but note how to specify two columns.

> It fills the top of the variable they share in common as NaNs

This is what an outer join does, and it uses fillers for that.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! My hspa_df has duplicate rows (some counties have several values for a single year). I am going to drop the duplicates (I just need the counties that exist in one df to create a binary variable in the other df).